# obtener el siguiente elemento de del valor de un iterable?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Tengo el siguiente código en Python:

```py
Tupla(1,0,1,0)

for i in tupla:
...
```

La cuestión es la siguiente, deseo imprimir el siguiente valor de i, ejemplo en primera vuelta de bucle se imprimiría 1, pero quiero que se imprima 0, ¿Cómo lo puedo lograr? Ya que me piden que evalúe el número anterior de i y el siguiente de i, si son iguales i valdrá 0.

Answer (score 0):

Fácil, iteramos en el rango de la lista para que así podamos acceder a sus índices y por ende a sus elementos.

```py
tupla = (1,0,1,0)

for i in range(len(tupla)): 
    actual = tupla[i]
    n=i
    if i == len(tupla)-1: n =-1
    siguiente = tupla[n+1]
    anterior = tupla[i-1]
    print(anterior,actual,siguiente)
```

Algo que debes saber es que en la primera iteración el valor de `i` será `0` por lo que al restarle 1 quedara como `tupla[-1]` y esto obtendrá el ultimo valor de la tupla.

Comment: No me funciona lo de siguiente = tupla[ i + 1] porque cuando corro el for me sale que está fuera de rango, y si pongo range(len(tupla)-1) la i no llega a la posición 4 de la tupla.

Comment: Entonces puedes poner una condición

Comment: Si, ya lo solucione, dándole muchas vueltas vi que si no era con el siguiente no iba a encontrar otra forma, entonces con un if lo solucione, muchas gracias por su ayuda Christian.